# Print line numbers (like NR) but restart numbering for each new field variable in $3

Tags: awk

Using AWK Can anyone tell me how to print a field similar to the NR function, except the numbering restarts when a new "id" is seen in column 3 ($3). 
using the command `'{print  $0 "\t" $3"-exon-"NR}'` numbers exons 1 through 20 **I want to restart the numbering for each new id in field $3 (ie.  497097, 19888, 20671, 18777 and 58175)**. For this file all the id numbers are on adjacent rows. I have put an example of the formatting I'm trying to code $6 below. my real file is over 250,000 rows and has many more fields. I'm assuming this is really easy but I haven't been able to find the correct solution.
Thanks!

```
chr gene    id  start   stop    exon_number  
1   Xkr4    497097  3216021 3216967 497097-exon-1  
1   Xkr4    497097  3421701 3421900 497097-exon-2  
1   Xkr4    497097  3670551 3671347 497097-exon-3  
1   Rp1 19888   4344599 4350090 19888-exon-1    
1   Rp1 19888   4351909 4352080 19888-exon-2  
1   Rp1 19888   4352201 4352824 19888-exon-3  
1   Sox17   20671   4491715 4492667 20671-exon-1  
1   Sox17   20671   4493099 4493405 20671-exon-2  
1   Lypla1  18777   4807913 4807981 18777-exon-1  
1   Lypla1  18777   4808454 4808485 18777-exon-2  
1   Lypla1  18777   4828583 4828648 18777-exon-3  
1   Lypla1  18777   4830267 4830314 18777-exon-4  
1   Lypla1  18777   4832310 4832380 18777-exon-5  
1   Lypla1  18777   4837000 4837073 18777-exon-6  
1   Lypla1  18777   4839386 4839487 18777-exon-7  
1   Lypla1  18777   4840955 4841131 18777-exon-8  
1   Lypla1  18777   4844962 4845015 18777-exon-9  
1   Rgs20   58175   4910473 4910661 58175-exon-1  
1   Rgs20   58175   4912313 4912547 58175-exon-2  
1   Rgs20   58175   4916896 4916979 58175-exon-3
```

Comment: please update your Q to show your best attempt to solve your problem. That is the only way we can help correct your understanding of how to use `awk` for such tasks. (Yes this should be very easy to solve). But can `497097` appear later in the file, or will records always be grouped together as you show here. Finally, isn't that `$3` for `497097`? Please update your Q, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, good that you have shown your expected output in code tags, it will be better if you could show us 1st sample Input and then expected output in code tags, so that we could more understand your query. Thanks and keep learning and sharing knowledge, cheers !!

Comment: Sorry you are correct "id" is $3, also the id records are grouped and are not repeated further down the file. I updated the Q to reflect both of these issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One-liner:**

```
awk  'FNR==1{print $0,"exon_number";next}p!=$3{c=0;p=$3}{print $0, $3"-exon-"++c}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

```
 awk  'FNR==1{                             # If first line read by awk
           print $0,"exon_number";         # print current record, 
                                           # and other header for new field
           next                            # we are done go to next line
       }
       p!=$3{                              # if p is not equal to 3rd column
           c=0;                            # reset counter variable
           p=$3                            # set variable p with 3rd column value                                   
                                           # Here you assume p mean previous value
       }
       {
          print $0, $3"-exon-"++c          # print current record, 
                                           # 3rd field 
                                           # "-exon-" string and
                                           # pre-increment variable c
       }
      ' infile
```

Comment: Thank you! The code also did exactly what I asked for. I modified it slightly to only output the calculated number in the "exon_number" field. `'FNR==1{print $0,"exon_number";next}p!=$3{c=0;p=$3}{print $0,++c}'` .  Your explanation was very helpful for me to  understand how the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $0,"exon_number";next} {printf("%s-exon-**%s**\n",$0 FS $3,val!=$3?(i=1):++i);val=$3}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
chr gene    **id**  start   stop   exon_number
1   Xkr4    497097  3216021 3216967 497097-exon-**1**
1   Xkr4    497097  3421701 3421900 497097-exon-**2**
1   Xkr4    497097  3670551 3671347 497097-exon-**3**
1   Rp1 19888   4344599 4350090 19888-exon-**1**
1   Rp1 19888   4351909 4352080 19888-exon-**2**
1   Rp1 19888   4352201 4352824 19888-exon-**3**
1   Sox17   20671   4491715 4492667 20671-exon-**1**
1   Sox17   20671   4493099 4493405 20671-exon-**2**
1   Lypla1  18777   4807913 4807981 18777-exon-**1**
1   Lypla1  18777   4808454 4808485 18777-exon-**2**
1   Lypla1  18777   4828583 4828648 18777-exon-**3**
1   Lypla1  18777   4830267 4830314 18777-exon-**4**
1   Lypla1  18777   4832310 4832380 18777-exon-**5**
1   Lypla1  18777   4837000 4837073 18777-exon-**6**
1   Lypla1  18777   4839386 4839487 18777-exon-**7**
1   Lypla1  18777   4840955 4841131 18777-exon-**8**
1   Lypla1  18777   4844962 4845015 18777-exon-**9**
1   Rgs20   58175   4910473 4910661 58175-exon-**1**
1   Rgs20   58175   4912313 4912547 58175-exon-**2**
1   Rgs20   58175   4916896 4916979 58175-exon-**3**
```

***PS:*** If you don't want `**` in above code then you could remove them from `printf`.

Comment: Thank you! The code did exactly what I asked for. I modified it slightly to only output the calculated number in the "exon_number" field. `'FNR==1{print $0,"exon_number";next} {printf("%s %s\n",$0 FS,val!=$3?(i=1):++i);val=$3}'`